# Running a Yocto system built with kas on qemu

Tags: yocto, qemu

I have a Yocto-based Linux system that is built using kas, or more accurately kas-container. The system is meant to run on an embedded device and it works there.

The purpose of this system is to run an application that consists of several middleware programs.

I'd like to make testing of the application easier by running it with QEMU.

I have previously used Yocto to build and run QEMU versions of systems, but this time I am not using Yocto (bitbake) directly but via kas. Just saying runqemu after building system doesn't work, because oe-init-build-env has never been called and runqemu is not found. Calling runqemu with absolute path is not working either because it is not finding a TUN interface, even though I have created one. Starting kas-container shell and calling runqemu there, on the other hand, is not working because of a TUN interface missing there too, and there I can't even create one myself.

If there is a standard way of using kas to run the QEMU build then I have not managed to find any instructions on how to do it. Is there one? I have already managed to build it, but haven't found a solution for running it.

Comment: When you use `kas`, you can use the `shell` command to execute regular commands in a prepared environment: `kas shell $PATH_TO_KAS_CONFIG` - or alternatively you can use a 1-liner to run whatever command you want, without dropping directly to command line:  `kas shell $PATH_TO_KAS_CONFIG -c "runqemu $arg1 $arg2"` (Though have no idea if it works with kas-container, never used it)

Comment: I can give that command but it gives an error because the TUN interface is not found and I have no idea how to create it inside the kas shell.